# MessageBox.show() function doesn't work sometime

Tags: c#, internet-explorer-7, windows-xp, c#-2.0

My MessageBox.Show() function works well when I started to double click myApp.exe.
But When I tried to attached the Application process with source code. and set breakpoint 
At the code below, It doesn't work. What I mean is the MessageBox didn't pop-up. And the code catched by another outer exception handling. Does it caused by multi-threading timing issue?

I don't know why?
Thanks.

```
if (File.Exists(myConfigFile))
{
    doc.Load(myConfigFile);
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Read " + myConfigFile + " failed, can't find the file",
    "Critical Warning",
    MessageBoxButtons.OK,
    MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

Comment: Look at your Task Bar.  I think you will find that the window for the MessageBox is appearing somewhere else on the Task Bar.  Click it, and the MessageBox will appear.

Comment: I checked and  my turn on Pop-up blocker didn't be turn on. I thought it possible doesn't caused by the reason.

Comment: Pop-up blockers only affect your internet browser; they have no effect on Winforms applications.

Comment: Are you sure that you are entering the `else` block of your statement?

Comment: Why your question is tagged `internet-explorer-7`? Are you using it in a web app?

Comment: @Danny Chen, Yes, I am using it in a web app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your source code has some differentiation from the attached process. you should rebuild your solution first, then start your newly created application exe from the solution folder "either at bin\debug or bin\release" depending on your build target, and then attach application process with source code.

Comment: I added `Thread.sleep(10000);` and attached the source code to app.exe. I double checked my code, and it works well. Eventually, my problem resolved by rebuild my solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`MessageBox.Show` can't be used in a web application. You can use `javascript` in your pages like `alert(123)`.